# moonliteco.in Transacions

Tags: lost-transactions

I have 5 Transactions sent by moonlite.in fausit but none ever show any bitcoin and they should. Here is the latest for you to have a look for me.Thank you. Isdaan. 
http://ltc.blockr.io/tx/info/f553aa1275908e6e95d89d1454b0f4ba571cf4fdbb9412d7c73917bb51a94bc7

Answer (score 1):

The block explorer says the transaction has been confirmed by block 1173986 which was mined several days before you posted your question. This means you received the money but your wallet software doesn't show it to you.

Make sure your wallet is connected to the internet. If you use a client which downloads the entire blockchain, wait for that process to finish. If you use a client which doesn't download the entire blockchain, make sure you are connected to other nodes / a server (depending on the kind of wallet). Possibly change the server your wallet connects to.